# Filesystem lock in Java

Tags: java, io, nio

I'm using a filesystem lock in some code when reading in lines from a file and processing them. This is because my architecture has more than one application server; I only want a single server to process each line to avoid data duplication.

I create a DTO in a helper method. The object is populated with the lock details, which can is returned by the helper method and can be subsequently queried to see whether the lock was successful. If so, the line in the file can be processed.

Usually, if two servers try and process the line in the file at the same time, an exception is thrown by one of them as the file has been locked by the other one. If this happens, my code catches the exception and just moves onto the next line in the file.

The lock is implemented below:

```
String filename = <Unique identifier of record being processed>;
File lockfile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), filename);
RandomAccessFile randomAccessfile = new RandomAccessFile(lockfile, "rw");
FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessfile.getChannel();

FileLockDTO fileLockDTO = new FileLockDTO();
fileLockDTO.setLockedfile(lockfile);
fileLockDTO.setRandomAccessfile(randomAccessfile);
fileLockDTO.setFileLock(fileChannel.tryLock());
```

For the vast majority of the time, the code works well. However on rare occasions, duplicate records appear, suggesting that there is an edge case where more than one application server can seemingly create a lock at exactly the same moment in time.

I've looked long & hard at the code and tried a multitude of tests but can not identify how this would happen. Just wondered if anyone has any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I'm using Java version 1.7.

Comment: Then you want to try and `Files.createFile(pathHere)`.

Comment: Having dueling app servers reading lines from a file does not seem likely to succeed. You need a real queueing system; you can use AMQ, or ZMQ, or MongoDB, or ...

Comment: are your lock files secondary files used purely for locking?  also, do you open the lock files in any other code?

Comment: @jtahlborn The files are purely used for locking in this scenario and are not utilised anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`FileLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) javadocs:

> Whether or not a lock actually prevents another program from accessing the content of the locked region is system-dependent and therefore unspecified. The native file-locking facilities of some systems are merely advisory, meaning that programs must cooperatively observe a known locking protocol in order to guarantee data integrity.

And from the [`FileChannel.tryLock()` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28%29): (emphasis is mine) An `OverlappingFileLockException` is thrown

> If a lock that overlaps the requested region is already held **by this Java virtual machine**, or if **another thread** is already blocked in this method and is attempting to lock an overlapping region

Here is a simple fail scenario for your app:

1. Server A queries to see if a lock exists on resource 1 => returns false
2. Server B queries to see if a lock exists on resource 1 => returns false
3. Server A runs lines 1-4 in your code snippet above and succeeds
4. Server B runs lines 1-4 in your code snippet above and succeeds (what would stop it?)
5. Server A creates the DTO
6. Server B creates the DTO (depending on the OS, the call to [`tryLock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28%29) may not stop anything)
7. Server A processes the "locked" record
8. Server B processes the "locked" record

Answer (score 0):

You must be relying on a null check inside FileLockDTO.setFileLock() or wherever you have it, if indeed you have it at all. All this seems too elaborate for me. I would just lock the actual line of the actual file you're reading rather than introduce these secondary lock files. Then if you encounter an existing lock you know to skip that line. Or else use a data structure that is capable of delivering each line once only and eliminate the whole problem, for example an MQ of some kind, or a database.

**EDIT** Downvoters and/or adherents of the theory that FileLocks don't work across JVMs or processes need to read the documentation.

Comment: @Asaph Unfortunately the Javadoc doesn't agree with you: "This file-locking API is intended to map directly to the native locking facility of the underlying operating system. Thus the locks held on a file should be visible to all programs that have access to the file, regardless of the language in which those programs are written."

Comment: I'm reading the docs and quoting and linking to them. An `OverlappingFileLockException` is thrown "If a lock that overlaps the requested region is already held by this Java virtual machine, or if another thread is already blocked in this method and is attempting to lock an overlapping region of the same file" -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock()

Comment: @Asaph That doesn't support your contention in any way. Nor does it contradict the part I have quoted. You're clutching at straws.